# Having trouble rereading a Lucene TokenStream

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene 4.6, and am apparently unclear on how to reuse a TokenStream, because I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
```

at the start of the second pass. I've read the Javadoc, but I'm still missing something. Here is a simple example that throws the above exception:

```
@Test
public void list() throws Exception {
  String text = "here are some words";
  TokenStream ts = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_46, new StringReader(text));
  listTokens(ts);
  listTokens(ts);
}

public static void listTokens(TokenStream ts) throws Exception {
  CharTermAttribute termAtt = ts.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
  try {
    ts.reset();
    while (ts.incrementToken()) {
      System.out.println("token text: " + termAtt.toString());
    }
    ts.end();
  }
  finally {
    ts.close();
  }
}
```

I've tried not calling `TokenStream.end()` or `TokenStream.close()` thinking maybe they should only be called at the very end, but I get the same exception.

Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Exception` lists, as a possible issue, calling `reset()` multiple times, which you are doing.  This is explicitly not allowed in the implementation of `Tokenizer`.  Since the the `java.io.Reader` api does not guarantee support of the `reset()` operation by all subclasses, the `Tokenizer` can't assume that the `Reader` passed in can be reset, after all.

You may simply construct a new TokenStream, or I believe you could call `Tokenizer.setReader(Reader)` (in which case you certainly must `close()` it first).

Comment: Thanks, femtoRgon. Resetting the Reader worked. I had misinterpreted the multiple reset() restriction in the exception to mean not calling it multiple times in a row, which in retrospect would be an odd restriction.

Comment: Please write in code what you did. The answer dosent make any sense. For starters Tokernizer.setReader is not a static method.

Comment: @ArunavSanyal, just saw this. It's been almost 2 years, but I think all I did to get my above test to work is to add `ts.setReader(new StringReader(text))` between the two calls to `listTokens(ts)`.