# Lucene TokenStream Exception

Tags: java, exception, lucene, token, tokenize

I've got exactly the same problem of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624339/having-trouble-rereading-a-lucene-tokenstream/24233922#24233922), so I'm opening a new question. Sorry to all for answered to the linked thread, BTW.

So: I'm trying to avoid the java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation.

I had a code very similar to the above linked:

```
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents( String fieldName, Reader reader ) {

String token;
CharArraySet stopWords = new CharArraySet( Version.LUCENE_48, 0, false );
stopWords.addAll( StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET );
keepWords.addAll( getKeepWordList() );

Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer( Version.LUCENE_48, reader );
TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter( Version.LUCENE_48, source );
filter = new StopFilter( Version.LUCENE_48, filter, stopWords );
ShingleFilter shiFilter = new ShingleFilter( filter, 2, 3 );
CharTermAttribute cta = shiFilter.addAttribute( CharTermAttribute.class );

try {
    shiFilter.reset();
    while( shiFilter.incrementToken() ) {

        token = cta.toString();
        System.out.println( token );
    }
    shiFilter.end();
    shiFilter.close();
} 
catch ( IOException ioe ) {

    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
return new TokenStreamComponents( source, filter );
}
```

I don't understand the proposed solution: what does it means "simply construct a new TokenStream" or "Resetting the reader"? I've tried both solution, like adding:

```
source.setReader( reader );
```

Or change to:

```
filter = new StopFilter( Version.LUCENE_48, filter, stopWords );
ShingleFilter shiFilter = new ShingleFilter( filter, 2, 3 );
```

But the error last. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are consuming everything in the filter and closing it before passing it back from the `createComponents` call.

You are, I assume, trying to debug how analysis works with this:

```
try {
    shiFilter.reset();
    while( shiFilter.incrementToken() ) {
        token = cta.toString();
        System.out.println( token );
    }
    shiFilter.end();
    shiFilter.close();
} 
catch ( IOException ioe ) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note, though, that when you are done with it, `shiFilter` is at the end of the stream, and has been closed.  You now pass it back from the method, in the TokenStreamComponents, when Lucene will now attempt to use it to index the documents.  It will call `reset()` first, and will throw the indicated exception for trying to use an already closed resource.

If you want to debug this, I'd recommend just creating an instance of your custom analyzer, and call `analyzer.tokenStream` to get the stream for debugging output.  If you really need to debug by iterating through the filter instance, rather than the analyzer, you'll need to build a separate one, rather than consuming the stream in `createComponents`.

Comment: So, if I understood right, putting that piece of code into createComponents involve an uncorrect use of `reset`, that is, will reset an already closed resource. It makes sense.

Then, I have to move that part where my custom analyzer is located. My purpose isn't debugging, anyway. I'd like to create custom Tokens, like selecting a neighborhood of certain words. I thought I should do this into createComponents.

Comment: If you want to do some processing to modify (or add, or remove) tokens in analysis, you should implement a [`TokenFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenFilter.html), and add it to you filter chain (just like your `ShingleFilter` or `StopFilter`, for instance).

Comment: Then the only thing I should do is to override the `incrementToken` method from the `TokenFilter` abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you are trying to do. I believe that you would want to get the get the bigrams and trigrams from the token stream in addition to the unigrams. The following code fragment (which I developed after a bit of cleaning of your code) runs for me and is the standard way of doing this.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.NGramTokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.shingle.ShingleFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.*;
import org.apache.lucene.util.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;

class TestAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

TestAnalyzer() {
    super();
}

protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents( String fieldName, Reader reader ) {
    String token;
    TokenStream result = null;

    Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer( Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, reader );
    result = new ShingleFilter(source, 2, 3);

    return new TokenStreamComponents( source, result );
}
}

public class LuceneTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestAnalyzer analyzer = new TestAnalyzer();

    try {
        TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("field", new StringReader("This is a damn test."));
        CharTermAttribute termAtt = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

        stream.reset();

        // print all tokens until stream is exhausted
        while (stream.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.println(termAtt.toString());
        }

        stream.end();
        stream.close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Were you able to get your expected output?

Comment: I'll try, then give feedback.
Anyway: my purpose is to analyze token's neighbourhood to get personalized N-grams. For instance, if I token match a prefixed word list, then add the 2 or 3 token before and after. Like, considering the token "fox", having "The brown fox jumps over" or similar.